# What is the difference between the two sentences including the work, revenge?

Tags: prepositions, transitivity

1. He **took revenge on** the trouble she made.
2. He **revenged** the trouble she made.

What is the difference between two sentences in meaning?
And why do I have to use verb phrase like 'take revenge on' instead of the word, 'revenge' though the two (take revenge on and revenge) has the same meaning?

Comment: Is this an actual quote you read somewhere? I feel that the second sentence should use the word *avenged* rather that *revenged*.

Answer (score 5):

Neither of your sentences is idiomatic.

With the noun *revenge*

- the preposition *for* introduces the offense.

  > Hamlet takes revenge for his father's murder.
- the preposition *on* introduces the person who committed the offense

  > Hamlet takes revenge on Claudius for his father's murder.

So what you want is "He took revenge on her for the trouble she caused."

The verb *revenge* may be either transitive or reflexive:

- The transitive verb takes the offense as its object

  > Hamlet revenged his father's murder
- The reflexive verb employs the same prepositional complements as the noun

  > Hamlet revenged himself on Claudius for his father's murder.